# How to add postgis extension to postgresql database in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis, gitlab-ci

I'm setting up test stage in `gitlab-ci.yml` file and I have error, when config postgis extension for postgresql databese.

I need DATABASE_URL, like `postgis://...` for my Django env

My latest version of `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: python:3.6

services:
  - postgres:9.6

variables:
  POSTGRES_DB: test_db
  POSTGRES_USER: test_user
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test_pass
  DATABASE_URL: "postgis://test_user:test_pass@postgres:5432/test_db"

stages:
  - test
  - build

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get -y install binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin postgis*
    - pip3 install pipenv
    - pipenv install --dev
    - export DATABASE_URL=$DATABASE_URL
    - pipenv run test
```

Gitlab Pipeline error response:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.5.0 (3afdaba6)
  on docker-auto-scale fa6cab46
Using Docker executor with image python:3.6 ...
Starting service postgres:9.6 ...
Pulling docker image postgres:9.6 ...
$ export DATABASE_URL=$DATABASE_URL
$ pipenv run test
/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/pixel-api-yo4gnz48/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/pixel-api-yo4gnz48/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 83, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.6/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory

django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.6/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

Comment: Why do you think you need an URI starting with `postgis://...`? It's just an extension to pg not a separate protocol.

Comment: @JakubKania because I use [dj-database-url](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url#url-schema) library for load DATABASE_URL

Answer (score 2):

Try to use alternative option from [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/install/postgis/#creating-a-spatial-database):

```
from django.contrib.postgres.operations import CreateExtension
from django.db import migrations

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    operations = [
        CreateExtension('postgis'),
        ...
    ]
```

Comment: thank you, I add this to my migrations, but have new errors with **gitlab-runner**:

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal", "GDAL", "gdal2.2.0", "gdal2.1.0", "gdal2.0.0", "gdal1.11.0", "gdal1.10.0", "gdal1.9.0"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.`

Comment: try to install `apt-get -y install binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a service that already has postgis and install the binary files, like this:

```
services:
  - mdillon/postgis:9.4

variables:
  POSTGRES_DB: "db_name"
  POSTGRES_USER: "db_user"
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "db_pwd"
  POSTGRES_HOST: "db"
  POSTGRES_PORT: "5432"
  DATABASE_URL: 
  "postgres://db_user:db_pwd@mdillon__postgis/db_name"

before_script:
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get -y install binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin
  - python -V
  - pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

References:
-https://www.hackzine.org/postgis-on-gitlab-ci.html